# execute function using JAVA reflection

Tags: java, class, reflection, methods, reference

I have the below classes, when I call myClass.doprocess(), I should get the string "hai", how can I achieve it?

```
public class myClass{
    public int doprocess(){
        dataClass objSt = new dataClass();
        Class newCls = objSt.getClass();
        Method[] methods = newCls.getMethods();
        for (Method method : methods) {
            if(method.getName() == "getList"){
                return method;
            }

        }
    }
 }

class dataClass{
   public String getList(){
        return "hai,";
    }
}
```

If I execute the above code am getting response as

```
public java.lang.String com.myproject.controller.dataClass.getList()
```

but I need the response to be the return value from getList function

Comment: Strings are compared with `.equals(String)`

Comment: `Method method` is not an `int`.

Comment: Your code does not compile, so you haven't really tested it successfully. How have you been resolving the compilation problems?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [getDeclaredMethod](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethod%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class...%29) to get a method with the given name and parameter set, then you can use the [Method.invoke(instance, params...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object...%29) to call the method.

```
class myClass {
    public String doprocess() throws SecurityException, NoSuchMethodException,
            IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException,
            InvocationTargetException {
        dataClass objSt = new dataClass();
        Method m = dataClass.class
                .getDeclaredMethod("getList", (Class<?>) null);
        return (String) m.invoke(objSt, (Object) null);
    }
}

class dataClass {
    public String getList() {
        return "hai,";
    }
}
```

Test

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SecurityException,
            IllegalArgumentException, NoSuchMethodException,
            IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
        myClass m = new myClass();
        System.out.println(m.doprocess());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your current code is can't compiled because your `doprocess` method is declared to return an `int` but your method body return `Method` object.

To call the method using reflection, use [invoke](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodInvocation.html).

Try this:

```
class myClass {
    public Method doprocess() {
        dataClass objSt = new dataClass();
        Class newCls = objSt.getClass();
        Method[] methods = newCls.getMethods();
        for (Method method : methods) {
            System.out.println(method.getName());
            if (method.getName() == "getList") {
                return method;
            }

        }
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Method m = new myClass().doprocess();
            if(m != null) System.out.println(m.invoke(new dataClass()));
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class dataClass {
    public String getList() {
        return "hai,";
    }
}
```